# C++ Error - missing closing quote with \

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, backslash, quote

I am using the `define` method in C++ with a backslash, in conjunction with an `ifstream`, which is called `a`. However, I get an error when **using** the backslash, which says:

> Error - missing closing quote.

I have tried doing `#define BACKSLASH \`, but that contains no value at all:

```
#define BACKSLASH '\'

if((char)a.get() == BACKSLASH // Error here)
{
     // BLAH BLAH BLAH
}
```

Comment: need to escape the backslash

Comment: `'\'` means that you are escaping single quote , so see Roger answer

Comment: It's funny that you tagged this with "backslash", when the tag description sort of tells you what the problem is. (To be clear, I'm not blaming you for not having read it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape it. So either:

```
#define BACKSLASH '\\'
```

Or:

```
if((char)a.get() == '\\')
{
     // BLAH BLAH BLAH
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#define BACKSLASH '\\'
```

instead of

```
#define BACKSLASH '\'
```

ie you need to escape the backslash. Since when `'\'` means that you are escaping single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cout << "\/";
```

or

```
cout << "\\";
```